# Time-series correlation if t is negatively correlated with t+1, t+2... but t+1, t+2... are positively correlated

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, definition, lags

What kind of time-series correlation are we talking about if t is negatively correlated with t+1, t+2, t+3,... but t+1, t+2, t+3,... are positively correlated? So for example, a positive value in t leads to decreasingly negative values in the future. Not knowing the number of lags ex-ante, I'd say it is a k-order negative autocorrelation?

Comment: I feel like there's a mistake here. If $T$ is negatively correlated with $T+1$ and $T+2$, then it doesn't make sense to say that $T+1$ will be positively correlated with $T+2$. The relationship between $T+1$ and $T+2$ will be the same as that of $T$ and $T+1$.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure. Let's say we have a positive value of 20 in T, which partially reverses in T+1 (-15) and T+2 (-5). In such a time series, T would be negatively correlated with T+1 and T+2, but T+1 and T+2 would be positively correlated. Or am I misinterpreting a fundamental concept here?

Comment: I don't think you're using the concept of correlation correctly. We talk about correlations between random variables. (Bigger values of $T$ result in smaller values of $T+1$) But not between specific values. We wouldn't say that $-15$ is positively correlated with $-5$.